# How do you combines columns using Tidyverse/Dplyr to create unique values for every repeated value?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a data frame that consists of two rows that I would like to combine into one. One of the rows has Days (different days that participants were being tested), and the other has the participant numbers ranging from 1-36 (individuals being tested). There are repeated participant numbers on different days, so I would like to create a variable that creates a new, unique participant number whenever the same number is repeated on a different day.

For instance, if there is a Participant 1 on days 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5, I would like to to create a column in which those repeated Participant 1s have turned into discernible participants.

In the code below, you can see how the data frame is for Day 1, and further down, there is more for Day 2 with repeated participant numbers with unique numbers. There are 5 days in total, and 36 participants per day, so at the end I would like to have participants 1-180 instead of 1-36 repeated 5 times.

I haven't yet gotten any code for this because I have no idea how to merge columns in that way. I only know how to add/subtract values or join columns.

Thank you in advance for your help!

[This screenshot gives you a feel for the repeated numbers as you can see different days][1]

````
    X Day question_ID Expert participant_ID Sequence estimate Reaction.time.1 Personal.Confidence Reaction.time.2 Social.Information Social.Estimation
1   1   1        1      0         1        1             5.5e+01           7.925                   2           5.617          9.500e+01           8.5e+01
2   2   1        1      0         4        2             8.0e+01           7.020                   1           4.898          8.700e+01           8.4e+01
3   3   1        1      0         3        3             6.0e+01           7.223                   1           3.479          8.700e+01           6.7e+01
4   4   1        1      0         2        4             8.6e+01           4.602                   1           5.086          7.800e+01           8.5e+01
5   5   1        1      0         5        5             5.0e+01           5.319                   1           5.632          7.800e+01           5.1e+01
6   6   1        1      0         6        6             5.8e+01           5.367                   1           4.820          6.700e+01           6.7e+01
7   7   1        1      0         7        7             8.8e+01           8.907                   1           6.786          6.700e+01           8.2e+01
8   8   1        1      0        12        8             8.5e+01           9.219                   1           5.585          6.600e+01           6.7e+01
9   9   1        1      0         8        9             5.0e+01           8.019                   1           8.073          7.200e+01           6.0e+01
10 10   1        1      0         9       10             6.0e+01          13.182                   2           5.788          6.900e+01           7.2e+01
11 11   1        1      0        10       11             8.2e+01          10.343                   2           8.003          6.600e+01           7.8e+01
12 12   1        1      0        11       12             8.0e+01           8.690                   2           6.801          7.000e+01           7.8e+01
13 13   1        1      0        13       13             8.4e+01           6.988                   3           7.518          7.600e+01           7.8e+01
14 14   1        1      0        18       14             7.8e+01           4.431                   4           5.195          7.800e+01           7.8e+01
15 15   1        1      0        14       15             8.0e+01          10.920                   2           6.365          7.800e+01           8.0e+01
16 16   1        1      0        15       16             8.0e+01           7.254                   2           4.539          7.800e+01           8.5e+01
17 17   1        1      0        17       17             6.5e+01           7.395                   2           4.602          8.100e+01           7.5e+01
18 18   1        1      0        16       18             5.8e+01           7.660                   1           5.632          8.000e+01           8.0e+01
19 19   1        1      0        20       19             7.0e+01           6.271                   1           5.538          8.000e+01           7.5e+01
20 20   1        1      0        23       20             6.0e+01          12.449                   1           5.991          7.600e+01           8.0e+01
21 21   1        1      0        22       21             8.0e+01           7.410                   2           5.569          7.800e+01           8.0e+01
22 22   1        1      0        19       22             1.0e+02          12.511                   5           8.362          7.800e+01           7.6e+01
23 23   1        1      0        24       23             9.0e+01           9.765                   2           7.675          7.800e+01           8.0e+01
24 24   1        1      0        21       24             6.0e+01          12.106                   1           8.221          7.800e+01           7.9e+01
25 25   1        1      0        30       25             8.8e+01           6.692                   1           4.758          7.800e+01           8.0e+01
26 26   1        1      0        28       26             7.5e+01           9.111                   5           9.485          7.900e+01           7.5e+01
27 27   1        1      0        29       27             8.6e+01          12.932                   3           6.318          7.800e+01           7.9e+01
28 28   1        1      0        25       28             8.9e+01          10.717                   3           4.415          7.800e+01           9.2e+01
29 29   1        1      0        27       29             9.0e+01           7.551                   2           6.942          8.200e+01           9.0e+01
30 30   1        1      0        26       30             8.0e+01           6.443                   1           4.150          8.700e+01           7.3e+01
31 31   1        1      0        35       31             8.0e+01           7.612                   2           6.038          8.500e+01           8.2e+01
32 32   1        1      0        36       32             8.6e+01           6.818                   3           7.941          8.100e+01           8.5e+01
33 33   1        1      0        32       33             8.6e+01           6.318                   3           6.178          8.000e+01           7.6e+01
34 34   1        1      0        31       34             7.5e+01           7.082                   1           5.148          8.100e+01           7.6e+01
35 35   1        1      0        34       35             8.8e+01           8.096                   1           7.270          7.900e+01           8.2e+01
36 36   1        1      0        33       36             8.0e+01           6.474                   4           4.804          7.800e+01           8.0e+01```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HdVDw.png
````

Comment: Can you share a short example and show expected output based on that. You can remove the columns which are not relevant so that it is easier to understand what you want. See this post to know how to share a reproducible example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269

Comment: If you have `dplyr` 1.0.0 you can try `df1 <- df %>% group_by(participant_ID, Day) %>%
  mutate(key = cur_group_id())`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Can you please edit your post to include your data (after dropping the unneeded columns).  The following code will generate a code snippet with 10 random records that you can paste into your original post: dput(dplyr::sample_n(YourDatasetsNameGoesHere, 10)). To use my code, you may need to install dplyr with: install.packages("dplyr").  Increase the sample size in the snippet until you have a few observations from a couple people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a unique code using `dplyr`. You can then `arrange` the data to sort it alphabetically by participant code, group it and add a sequential number using `row_number()`. The dplyr function `unite` will also remove the original columns by default, though you can specify `remove=FALSE` to preserve them:

```
require(dplyr)

df%>%
unite("participant.code", c("Day","participant_ID"), sep="_")%>%
group_by(participant.code)%>%
arrange(participant.code)%>%
mutate(participant.seq=row_number())
```

This will add a sequential number to all participants, assigning the same number if the same participant appears twice in a day. Another option is to altogether skip the `unite` line of code and specify `group_by(Day,participant_ID)`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I appreciate it! 

While the `unite` function is working to merge the two columns, I am left with new participant numbers like `1_1` and `2_35` instead of new numbers. For instance, `1_1` (Day 1 Participant 1) would stay as Participant `1`, but `2_35` would become Participant `70`, for instance.

Is there a way to do that instead?